# Instance variable reset to nil at ViewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, reset, instance-variables

I have an object that inherits from `UIViewController`. In this object, I have a instance variable that contain the profile of the user (type: `UserProfile`). I'm setting this variable before `ViewDidLoad()` but once I enter in it, the variable is reseted to `nil`...

Here is my code:

```
    class MapViewController: UIViewController {

        var userProfile: UserProfile!

        required init(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
        }

        override init() {
            super.init()
        }

        override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
            super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        }

        func setProfile(userProfile: UserProfile) {        
            self.userProfile = userProfile
            //self.userProfile is OK
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.userProfile is equal to nil....
       }
}
```

Here is the declaration of the controller:

```
self.mapViewController = MapViewController()
self.mapViewController?.setProfile(self.userProfile)
//The controller is pushed through the storyboard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you create a new instance of MapViewController here:

```
self.mapViewController = MapViewController()
self.mapViewController?.setProfile(self.userProfile)
//The controller is pushed through the storyboard
```

You should use your destinationcontroller from segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) 
{
    if (segue.identifier == "showSecondViewController")
    {
        var second = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        second.setProfile(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Urg indeed, I'm dealing with 2 different instances... Not use to storyboards, I'm going to check this segue story. Thanks for the quick answer !

Comment: Is it possible to do this :

`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
self.mapViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapViewController") as MapViewController`

Comment: Sure, but you haven't same instance as connected with segue. With this reason your creating a new instance too.